# aiohttp.web: random CancelledError's

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an `aiohttp.web` application that interacts with `elasticsearch` and `redis` using `aioes` and `aioredis`. It's very simple: one event loop and a few request handlers. It works ok on testing server, but in production when server load reaches 100 rps, this error starts appearing randomly:

```
CancelledError: null
  File "visio_longer/views/communicate/receiver.py", line 80, in process_message
    await self.process_ulog_batch(type, batch)
  File "visio_longer/views/communicate/receiver.py", line 240, in process_ulog_batch
    await self.redis.rpush("playback_item_playback", *playbacks_json)
  File "asyncio/futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "asyncio/tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "asyncio/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise CancelledError
```

It happens in both `elasticsearch` and `redis` clients in random places and at random times. Server load is no more than 5-10%, it's not an elasticsearch/redis timeout issue (i've tried causing timeouts and exceptions were different), it's just something is cancelling my futures. The question is: who is? aiohttp, aioes and aioredis versions are latest from pip.